# Objective C : Adding Action On Array of Buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, icarousel

i'm a newbie in Objective-C can someone help me out here? I am trying to make a carousel of button but i failed to do it.

What i got it just displaying all the buttons on load and that's it. I can't add action on each button, I mean tagging them.

It's my first to do declare button in this way.
The buttons are not working.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    mainHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feat.png"]];
    [mainHolder setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainHolder setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    [self.view addSubview: mainHolder];

    header = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]];
    [header setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 50)];
    [header setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainHolder addSubview:header];

    // The items to be displayed in the carousel
    items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picOne.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picTwo.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picThree.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picFour.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picFive.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picSix.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picSeven.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picEight.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picNine.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picTen.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"picEleven.png"],
             nil];

    // Initialize and configure the carousel
    carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    carousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
    carousel.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:carousel];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [items count];
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UIImage *image = [items objectAtIndex:index];
    imageChoices = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(253, 150, 518, 389)] autorelease];
    [imageChoices setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageChoices setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageChoices setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageChoices.titleLabel.font = [imageChoices.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [imageChoices addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    imageChoices.tag=index;
    return imageChoices;

}

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //I don't know how to tag each button here.
    switch(sender.tag){

    case 1:{
        NSLog(@"Photo1");
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        NSLog(@"Photo2");
    }
    case 3:{
        NSLog(@"Photo3");
    }
        break;
    case 4:{
        NSLog(@"Photo4");
    }
        break;
    case 5:{
        NSLog(@"Photo5");
    }
        break;   
}
}
```

Comment: Be more specific about what is failing.

Comment: What about `NSUInteger index = sender.tag`?

Comment: @trojanfoe there you go i edited it. my buttons are not working.

Comment: In would recommend to try using interface builder, if you don't you are not honouring the Model-View-Controller separation, and there is nothing worse than inheriting someones else code where they have done all the interface in code. I am currently in the process of rebranding an iPhone app I inherited from another developer, and what should of been at most two days work has taken oven a week because either the previous developer was too lazy to learn to use interface builder or thought he was being really clever doing all of the interface stuff in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the target method this way:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    switch(sender.tag){

        case 1:{
            NSLog(@"Photo1");
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            NSLog(@"Photo2");
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            NSLog(@"Photo3");
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            NSLog(@"Photo4");
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            NSLog(@"Photo5");
            break;
        }
        default:{
            NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIButton *sendButton = (UIButton *)sender; //No need of this! We already have sender

    switch(sendButton.tag)
    {

        //.......

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UIImage *image = [items objectAtIndex:index];

    //Instead of adding single UIButton, add separate for each carousel.
    UIButton *imageChoices = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(253, 150, 518, 389)] autorelease];
    [imageChoices setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imageChoices setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageChoices setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    imageChoices.titleLabel.font = [imageChoices.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [imageChoices addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    imageChoices.tag=index; //print index, that it should be unique or not?

    return imageChoices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `carousel.delegate = self;` In your loadview method and then implement

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)crsl didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index { }
```